# Documentum webtop URL Format to open file without prompts

Tags: documentum, webtop

We are working with a Documentum instance via the webtop interface.
We need to download a set of files in a specific way.
For this we need a URL format which will, by default, be a "Download" link.

The links we have are shown in the Webtop interface and include an ObjectID but when those links are taken they go to an intermediate web page where there are various options for Open, Edit, View etc  - and these options don't allow for the unattended access we are after.

URLs we do have look like this

xxhttp://zzhostname/webtop/drl/objectId/090187e380401713
xxhttp://zzhostname/webtop/drl/objectId/090187e380426ee4

We were hoping that there is some sort of additional parameter we can add to the URL to make it work as a Download - the kind of thing we have in other environments.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to DLR in webtop guide. this will help you to achieve what you are looking for.